# Explorer-like FTP client for Windows, open source and well-maintained

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, ftp, sftp

I need an FTP client for Windows

Requirements:

- Graphical and user-friendly
- Feels like a Windows Explorer window, supports drag and drop
- No nags/ads/spyware
- Open source
- Supports FTPS, SFTP, and all modern authentication mechanisms
- Well-maintained. While FTP is not bleeding-edge, I want to avoid programs that has not received a single commit in more than 6 months. The most recent commits the better.

Comment: The closed question is unclear, and has many highly-voted answers answers that are about a problem that only existed 5 years ago. I feel that a new question is more useful and fairer to answerers, but I am open to other opinions.

Comment: Linked question: [Free FTP client for Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10471/free-ftp-client-for-windows)

Comment: for anyone who doesn't need sftp/ftps: windows explorer itself has an ftp client. just type `ftp://server.com` into the location bar. (as an answer to this question, though, i recommend the already-suggested winscp.)

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow: +1. Even though it's not open-source, it works well and is easy to use. It's usually what I tell noobies to use when I send a link. It's possible to add login info so that they don't even need to type any password : `ftp://username:p4ssw0rd@example.com` It needs to be clear that it's Windows Explorer, not Internet Explorer, though.

Answer (score 64):

[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) matches all your requirements.

- Graphical: Yes – There are two alternative interfaces:

  1. [Commander interface](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_commander):

     [image: Commander interface]
  2. [Explorer interface](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_explorer):

     [image: Explorer ingterface]
- Feels like a Windows explorer window: Yes – [One of the interfaces](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_explorer) is explicitly designed after Windows File Explorer.
- Supports drag and drop: Yes – Both between file panels and between other applications.
  [Uploading via drag&drop](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_upload#dragdrop)
  [Downloading via drag&drop](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_download#dragdrop)
- No nags/ads/spyware: Yes.
- Open source: Yes – [GPL license](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/license)
- Supports FTPS, SFTP: [Yes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/protocols)
- All modern authentication mechanisms: Yes – SSH (for SFTP and SCP) is based on the up-to-date version of PuTTY. TLS/SSL (for FTPS, WebDAVS and Amazon S3) is based on up-to-date version of OpenSSL.
- Well-maintained: Yes – Over [1000 commits](https://github.com/winscp/winscp/commits/master) and [18 releases](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/history) in the last year.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Supports FTP, FTPS, SCP, SFTP, WebDAV and Amazon S3 file transfer protocols.

Comment: WinSCP is one of the few programs I'll trully miss when Windows 7 stops being viable.

Comment: @zero298 Why? WinSCP works fine in windows 10 does it not?

Comment: thank you for creating winscp! it is _still_ one of those must-have programs on a fresh installation of windows.

Comment: Bonus.  there is also nuget libraries if you want to "code up" the functionality this provides.  (even though i'm a long time user of FileZilla, I like this one too).  https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinSCP/

Comment: @Trotski94 Yes, it works with Windows 10 (there is even a Windows Store-friendly install option). My guess is zero298 must be refusing to use/acknowledge Windows 10 for ideological reasons.

Comment: @Trotski94 I know a few people who have said that they'll move away from Windows after Windows reaches EOL, perhaps that's the case for zero298.

Answer (score 7):

I have used the 3 following FTP clients during the past years so here is my feedback:

- **WinSCP**: the one that I currently use. There is a portable version, just one .exe file (and the .ini file for configuration). Don't forget to turn on the "Explorer" interface: 
  *View > Preferences > Environment > Interface > Explorer*, which is (IMHO) handier.

  [image]

  Benchmark: it is super fast! **4.5 sec** to be connected to the server (time measured from double-click on the WinSCP icon until the server's file list is displayed).
- **Cyberduck**: I've used it during years, it is great (double-click on a file => edit locally, CTRL+S in the local text editor => automatically reuploads without any popup, like WinSCP). The only drawback is that it is ... a bit slow. (Is it because it uses .NET framework and not pure WinAPI?).

  Benchmark: on my i5 laptop, it takes 5 sec. for the UI to show (after double-clicking on the Cyberduck icon), and **a total of 19 sec to be connected to the server** (time measured from double-click on the Cyberduck icon until the server's file list is displayed).
- **FileZilla**: a well-known FTP client, which once was probably the most popular one. I don't use it anymore because of [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/150/ftp-file-editor-and-uploader-thats-also-a-code-editor#comment323_160), which totally ruins its user experience, from a developer prospective.